# Iterate through columns in data frame taking its average and comparing it with every value within the same column

Tags: r, function, data-manipulation

I need to write a simple function that first iterates over every column in a data frame, takes its average, then iterates through every row in that column, takes its value and compares with a value that corresponds to a retrospective date from the same column (-2 days) as well as with a column mean and returns "All okay" if a value > mean and retrospective value and "Anomaly" if a value < mean and a retrospective value.

Here is a data frame I have:

```
df <- data.frame(startdate = as.Date('2010-11-1') + 0:4,
                 salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800, 40586, 86750), 
                 bonus = c(350, 400, 170, 180, 95))
```

that looks like this:

```
  startdate  salary bonus
1 2010-11-01  21000   350
2 2010-11-02  23400   400
3 2010-11-03  26800   170
4 2010-11-04  40586   180
5 2010-11-05  86750    95
```

Definitely, I have tried different approaches to solve that but all that I came up now was to create a function that takes a data frame and a column name as arguments and does the job.

How to make it passing through all the columns in a data frame and returning a desired output?

Assumed that date is ordered (ascending) and doesn't have any duplicates. In original dataset I have 30 rows and about 14 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. You will need the package `dplyr` for it to work, as it uses the `lag()` function:

```
FOO <- function(df){
  # calculate colmeans
  means <- sapply(df, mean)

  # generate matrix with value 2 if both conditions are TRUE
  output <- as.data.frame((df > means) + (df > sapply(df, dplyr::lag, 2)))

  # insert string values
  output[output < 2] <- "Anomaly"
  output[output == 2] <- "All okay"

  return(output)
}

> FOO(df)
  startdate   salary   bonus
1      <NA>     <NA>    <NA>
2      <NA>     <NA>    <NA>
3  All okay  Anomaly Anomaly
4  All okay All okay Anomaly
5   Anomaly All okay Anomaly
```

It'll return `NA` for the first two rows, as there are no comparison values available for the second condition.

Comment: I think I should become more familiar with the apply family. thank you!

Comment: The `apply` family is insanely helpful. Also, lists. They are great, don't let anyone tell you otherwise.